# Public transport tickets for a few days in Düsseldorf?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, germany, dusseldorf

I'm going to be spending 3 days in Düsseldorf, for a mixture of work and holiday, so I'm going to need to do a fair bit of travelling around the city to get to both meetings and sightseeing/museums/etc.

Are there any public transport tickets I could get which would cover me for the three days for a number of journeys, to avoid needing to buy individual tickets each trip? And if so, is it possible to get one that covers both the city centre area and the trip to/from the airport? Or would I be better off getting a return ticket from the airport into town, and then some sort of multi-trip/multi-day ticket once I'm there?

Comment: Düsseldorf Airport **is in city area** so you won't need a special ticket to go to/from the airport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at the [VRR](http://www.vrr.de/en/fares-and-tickets/index.html) and [Rheinbahn](http://www.rheinbahn.com) sites and it seems your best option is to buy a [day ticket (Tagesticket)](http://www.rheinbahn.com/tickets/Seiten/Tickets-for-occasional-travellers.aspx) every day. It costs 6.80 Euros and allows unlimited travel within Duesseldorf.

Single fares are 2.70 Euros, so if you do 3 or more rides, you're better off using the day ticket.

There is no 3-day pass available, just day tickets and weekly/monthly tickets.

The farelevel from the airport to the center is A2, while the day ticket is available for levels A,B,C,D and E. It is not totally clear on the web sites, whether the day ticket covers the airport.

[This page](http://www.rheinbahn.de/tickets/alletickets/Seiten/preisstufe_a.aspx) covers both A1 and A2 and lists a single price for the day ticket: €6.80, so I assume you are fine with a day ticket level A for the airport.

Comment: The Rheinbahn [first time user page](http://www.rheinbahn.com/pages/firsttime.aspx) might be worth linking to too - it includes the zone info such as `For all journeys within Düsseldorf or other towns, a price level A ticket is all you need`

Answer (score 2):

I live in D'dorf and what @Peter Hahndorf says is the right option. If you plan to take bus or train more than 3 times, buy a tagesticket every day.

The Tagesticket is valid in all farelevels, so you will not need to pay more for going to the airport. Here just to say there are 2 airports serving Düsseldorf, "Dusseldorf-airport" and Weeze (ryanair). Weeze is about 100km. from D'dorf, but the tagesticket is valid for both. 
You could also visit Cologne without paying more!